# Using adfonic in android

Tags: android

Good day!

I'd like to ask, if here is anyone, who could share information, links or tutorials about using adfonic android API?

I know about [Android SDK](http://developer.adfonic.com/index.php/Android_SDK), but there is no info about how to use it in code.

For now, I need only to send request before drawing view, so some ad there already is in view, when I place it somewhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The from code example is hidden a bit within the docs under "AdfonicView". You can make the ad request before displaying it to the user using AdfonicView.

1 Add the sdk jar to your project build path
2 Add the perms and activity to your manifest - see developer wiki for optional params

```
     
    `Insert before "application" opening XML tag
    a) uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    b) uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    c) uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

    Insert within "application" XML tag
    activity android:name="com.adfonic.android.AdfonicActivity"`
```

3 Make sure you have a container/layout to hold the ad
4 Make the ad request (test id 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222) and display to user

```
    `@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AdfonicView ad = new AdfonicView(this); 
        String adSlotId = "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"; 
        Request adRequest = new Request.RequestBuilder().withSlotId(adSlotId).withAllowLocation(true).withIsMale(false).build(); 
        ad.setRequest(adRequest); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ViewGroup container = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.adHolder));
        container.addView(ad);
    }`
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to email support@adfonic.com

Best regards,
Graeme

Comment: Thanks! Now I have some example of how to use it in code.
But still, when I draw view I have a blank screen for about a second.
P.S. where exactly this (and maybe some other) code example are hidden? :)